SQL Query - adding PTO hours
SELECT
   w.`Week Start Date` AS `Week Start Date`,
   SUM(toff.`Leave Taken`) AS `Time Off`,
   w.`Week End Date` AS `Week End Date`,
   u.`User Name` AS `User`,
   toff.`Start Date` AS `Start Date`,
   toff.`End Date` AS `End Date`
FROM  "WorkDays by Week" w
FULL OUTER JOIN "Active Users" u
LEFT JOIN "Employee (Zoho People)" emp ON u.`User Name`  = emp.`Employee Name`
LEFT JOIN "Approved and Pending Time Off" toff ON emp.`ID`  = toff.`Employee ID`
       AND  toff.`Start Date`  BETWEEN w.`Week Start Date`  AND  w.`Week End Date`
GROUP BY 
     w.`Week Start Date`,
     w.`Week End Date`,
     u.`User Name`,
     toff.`Start Date`,
     toff.`End Date`;

This is in Zoho. Trying to add PTO hours together that have the same week start date (because we have different PTO buckets that are being averaged together and throwing off employee hours). The query executes but doesn’t sum anything. For example, there’s an employee who is being marked down for only 20 hours for one work week. He used 40 hours of PTO in 2 different buckets and they’re being averaged together to sum 20. Trying to make this query to add those hours together so I don’t run into this issue but the query isn’t summing anything. Any help appreciated, this is driving me crazy.
